# When I run my android project that an error has been occurred.

Tags: android

When I run the App this error has been occured.

"Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1"

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter();
    maven{
        url  "https://c2call.com/archiva/repository/release/"
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.c2call.android:c2callsdk:1.6.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.reveriegroup.islammortuza"
        minSdkVersion 16
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hit this http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java.exe+finished+with+non-zero+exit+value+1

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "invalidate caches & restart"?
Sometimes there are some conflicts with files. 
A "clean project" and "rebuild" can help.